# How to Validate an Email address in React using functional components?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project in that project I have a form, In that form I am trying to do

Validation for an email address, but I don't know how to apply all these.

What I am expecting is, In input tag if I type mark, then If I go to another Input tag it has to

Show me some kind of message above Input tag like this, please enter a valid email address.

This is Form.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Form.css';

const Form = () => {

    const validation = (email) => {
        const result = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return result.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    }


    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-4'>
                    <div className='mainForm'>
                        <form>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" />
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those are basic problem in all JS code base, you need to catch the input event, using onChange, onBlur, On...etc and bind those event to your react class, like

```
return <input type=”email” name=”email” value={this.state.email} 
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
```

then on the handleChange you can call the email validation

```
handleChange(event){
   var email = event.target.value;
   // do what ever you want
   validation(email);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Khairu Aqsara I tried your code why it is showing any error If I type mark on Input tag

Comment: that because the input using onChange event, if you want to Fires the moment that the element loses focus, you need to use onBlur event., you can see this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873485/using-onblur-with-jsx-and-react